# Nested Json php for loop status[0] issue

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

Hi I have a Json format like below:

```
{
   "result":0,
   "status":[
      {
         "id":"00001",
         "vid":"yes"
      },
      {
         "id":"00002",
         "vid":"yes"
      },
      {
         "id":"00003",
         "vid":"no"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to use the `json_decode` function in PHP to decode the `id` values such as below:

```
 00001
 00002
 00003
```

here is the code I am using:

```
$url = file_get_contents("URL");

foreach(json_decode($url, true) as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value->status[0] as $key1=>$value1){
        echo $value1->id;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with `status[0]` as far as I know using `status[0]` is the only way to select the `status` key. However I can't get the loop to work correctly.

I get the error: `Trying to get property of non-object` meaning `status[0]` is not finding `status` in the Json array however I have no idea why this is since it works when I pull a value like:
 `$id = $url->status[0]->id;`

If anyone has any suggestions or advice I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Did you look up what json_decode does with `true` parameter?  `url` is a poor choice for the variable name.

Comment: Also see [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29308898) for some examples. The first `foreach` is pointless, and the second should just loop over `["status"]`. Would be simpler with [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes I have but I left it in from prototyping.. thanks

Comment: @mario Thanks,  the array_column function will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed some commas from your json data.

Code: demo: https://3v4l.org/C1Mda

```
$json = '{"result":0,"status":[{"id":"00001"},{"id":"00002"},{"id":"00003"}]}';

foreach(json_decode($json, true)['status'] as $status){
    echo $status['id'] , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
00001
00002
00003
```

Because you are using json_decode's `true` parameter, an array is generated.  You need to use square bracket syntax.

Or you can use objects:

```
foreach(json_decode($json)->status as $status){
    echo $status->id , "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid look { "id":"00001", } 
And json_decode( $json, false ) should be.

working solution:

```
$json = '{
"result":0,
"status":[{"id":"00001"},
  {"id":"00002"},
  {"id":"00003"}
]
}';

$data = json_decode($json, false);

foreach ($data->status as $status){
    echo $status->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the `id` values from the `status` element of your JSON (once it is corrected by removing the superfluous commas):

```
$ids = array_column(json_decode($json, true)['status'], 'id');
print_r($ids);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 00001
    [1] => 00002
    [2] => 00003 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TktI7)